# Use my own images with tensorflow?

Tags: android, tensorflow

I am working with this demo of tensorflow : https://github.com/miyosuda/TensorFlowAndroidDemo (Android Studio project without Bazel)

Can I use tensorflow with my own images ? How ?
Is there any example to set a new dataset?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android

Comment: this is not what I'm looking for. I want to do that using this project : https://github.com/miyosuda/TensorFlowAndroidDemo

Comment: Can I use tensorflow with my own image dataset ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You have to setup your own tensorflow environment first, using virtualenv (or docker or anaconda) first ( refer https://www.tensorflow.org/install/ )

2) And then, clone tensorflow source repo : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

3) After that, you should build several files for training/testing your own images and creating/optimizing graph files such as retrain, optimize_for_inference, quantization, etc.

4) Put your own images in appropriate classified names in the training folder

5) start training

Refer this page for how to (re)train images and put them onto android demo:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html#0
(This tutorial assumes you're using docker, but virtualenv and/or anaconda is almost same in how to do it)

and this Peter Warden's blog: https://petewarden.com/2016/09/27/tensorflow-for-mobile-poets/ for mobile implementation (it's based on ios example but can be applied to android also)